Error: Resource type '/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspace' is invalid for property 'properties.workspaceId'
I'm trying to create a function app and update the diagnostic settings through PowerShell script to existing Log Analytics Workspace that is residing in different subscription. However throwing error while updating with below error,
ERROR: Resource type '/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspace' is invalid for property'properties.workspaceId'. Expected types are 'microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces.
It has something to do with the workspace ID as I noticed hardcoding the workspace ID successfully retrieves and update the diagnostic settings.
PowerShell Script:
[CmdLetBinding()]

param(
[string] $SubscriptionId,
[string] $BusinessFunAppRGName,
[string] $BusinessFunAppName,
[string] $laWorkspaceRGName,
[string] $laWorkspaceName,
[string] $lawSubscriptionId

)
$ResourceId = "/subscriptions/$SubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$BusinessFunAppRGName/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites/$BusinessFunAppName"
$diagSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $ResourceId
if($diagSettings)
{
Write-Host "Diagnostics Settings Found"
}
else
{
Write-Host "Diagnostics Settings Not Found, Applying settings..."
$metric = @()
$log = @()
$metric += New-AzDiagnosticSettingMetricSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category AllMetrics
$log += New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category FunctionAppLogs

New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name "DiagnosticSettings" `
    -ResourceId $ResourceId `
    -Log $log -Metric $metric `
    -WorkspaceId "/subscriptions/$lawSubscriptionId/resourceGroups/$laWorkspaceRGName/providers/microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces/$laWorkspaceName" `


                  
        
Write-Host "Done"

}
Workflow file sample:
    - name: 'Update diagnostics settings' 
  uses: azure/powershell@v1
  with:
      azPSVersion: "latest"
      inlineScript: |

        arm-templates/business-subscription-afna/update-diagnostics.ps1 `
          -SubscriptionId ${{ github.event.inputs.businessSubscriptionId }} `
          -BusinessFunAppRGName ${env:parameters.resourceGroup.value} `
          -BusinessFunAppName ${env:parameters.funcAppName.value} `
          -laWorkspaceRGName ${env:parameters.mgmtlaWorkspaceRGName.value} `
          -laWorkspaceName ${env:parameters.mgmtlaWorkspaceName.value} `
          -lawSubscriptionId ${env:parameters.mgmtlawSubscriptionId.value} 
      failOnStandardError: $true


The error message you are seeing indicates that the workspaceId property is not set to a valid resource ID for a Log Analytics workspace. The error message suggests that the expected resource type is microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces, but the actual resource type is /microsoft.operationalinsights/workspace.

You can fetch the Workspace resource ID instead of hardcoding it directly.
$wRID= Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -Name "workspacename" -ResourceGroupName "RG_NAme"
$wRID.ResourceId
New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name "DiagnosticSettings"     -ResourceId $ResourceId
-Log $log -Metric $metric      -WorkspaceId $wRID.ResourceId

$metric = @()
$log = @()
$metric += New-AzDiagnosticSettingMetricSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category AllMetrics
$log += New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category FunctionAppLogs
$wRID= Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -Name "$mgmtlaWorkspaceName" -ResourceGroupName "$mgmtlaWorkspaceRGName"
$wRID.ResourceId New-AzDiagnosticSetting -Name "DiagnosticSettings"      -ResourceId $ResourceId
-Log $log
-Metric $metric `
-WorkspaceId $wRID.ResourceId
not sure if I have modified code properly, pls correct me.

The error message you are seeing indicates that the workspaceId property is not set to a valid resource ID for a Log Analytics workspace. The error message suggests that the expected resource type is microsoft.operationalinsights/workspaces, but the actual resource type is /microsoft.operationalinsights/workspace.
Here is the updated script to create a DiagnosticSetting for a Function App.
    $RGName = "RG-Name"
    $LAWName = "LAW Name"
    $FunName = "FunctionAppName"
    
    $FunctionApp = Get-AzWebApp -ResourceGroupName $RGName -Name $FunName
    $Workspace = Get-AzOperationalInsightsWorkspace -Name $LAWName -ResourceGroupName $RGName
    
    if (!$Workspace) {
        Write-Host "Log Analytics Workspace not found in the specified subscription and resource group."
        return
    }
    
    $DiagnosticSettings = Get-AzDiagnosticSetting -ResourceId $FunctionApp.Id
    
    if ($DiagnosticSettings) {
        Write-Host "Diagnostics Settings Found"
    } else {
        Write-Host "Diagnostics Settings Not Found, Applying settings..."
    
        $MetricSettings = New-AzDiagnosticSettingMetricSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category AllMetrics
        $LogSettings = New-AzDiagnosticSettingLogSettingsObject -Enabled $true -Category FunctionAppLogs
    
        $WorkspaceId = $Workspace.ResourceId
    
        $Parameters = @{
            Name = "DiagnosticSetting"
            ResourceId = $FunctionApp.Id
            Log = $LogSettings
            Metric = $MetricSettings
            WorkspaceId = $WorkspaceId
        }
    
        New-AzDiagnosticSetting @Parameters
    
        Write-Host "Done"
    }

Output:

After running the script, diagnostics have been created for the Function App.

If I run the same script again, it detects the diagnostics and does not create a new one again.


Thank you Venkat, I have tried your suggestion but the issue here is my LAW workspace is in different subscription where it is failing to fetch from function app subscription.

Do you have access to that subscription? If yes, how are you accessing two subscriptions at a time via a Management group?

consider these subscriptions are under same management group and on single tenant.

If you have access to the management group, try connecting to it. If you are connecting from a function, ensure that your function app has access to the Log Analytics Workspace (LAW), which may be in a different subscription.
